# Stack three tables sideways

Tags: tables, rotating

I need to stack three sideway tables. My code makes Latex remove the captions somehow. It reports floatrow error, caption(s) lost. Is there also a way to align all three tables to the bottom of the page? Thanks in advance!

[image: output result]

```
\documentclass[A4, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{rotating}

\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}
\let\origref\ref
\def\ref#1{\textbf{\origref{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[!h]
\footnotesize
\caption{Sample A, B and C calculations}

\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{1.5cm}p{1cm}p{1.5cm}p{1cm}p{1.5cm}p{1cm}} 
\hline\hline
\rule{0pt}{3ex}
\textbf{Compound} & \textbf{Sample A (area)} & \textbf{\% A} & \textbf{Sample B (area)} & \textbf{\% B} & \textbf{Sample C (area)} & \textbf{\% C} \\[0.5ex]
\midrule
Benzene & 97166 & 29.796 & 118538 & 28.804 & 73071 & 34.719 \\
Chlorobenzene & 79837 & 24.482 & 101977 & 24.780 & 52619 & 25.002 \\
1,2-dichlorobenzene & 86195 & 26.432 & 111483 & 27.090 & 50634 & 24.058 \\
Trichlorobenzene & 62905 & 19.290 & 79534 & 19.326 & 34138 & 16.221 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%

\vspace{2.5\baselineskip}
\caption{Unknown 1, 2 and 3 calculations}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}}
\hline\hline
\rule{0pt}{3ex}
\textbf{Compound} & \textbf{Unk 1 area} & \textbf{Unk 1 area \% } & \textbf{Unk 2 area} & \textbf{Unk 2 area \% } & \textbf{Unk 3 area} & \textbf{Unk 3 area \% } \\[0.5ex]
\midrule
Benzene & 37439 & 13.666 & 44157 & 13.076 & 46672 & 12.987 \\
Chlorobenzene & 68335 & 24.943 & 83331 & 24.676 & 88155 & 24.531 \\
1,2-dichlorobenzene & 80497 & 29.382 & 100331 & 29.710 & 107083 & 29.798 \\
Trichlorobenzene & 87692 & 32.009 & 109881 & 32.538 & 117455 & 32.684 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%

\vspace{2.5\baselineskip}
\caption{Unknown 1, 2 and 3 calculations}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}}
\hline\hline
\rule{0pt}{3ex}
\textbf{Compound} & \textbf{Unk 1 Corr. Area} & \textbf{Unk 1 \% Comp.} & \textbf{Unk 2 Corr. Area} & \textbf{Unk 2 \% Comp.} & \textbf{Unk 3 Corr. Area} & \textbf{Unk 3 \% Comp.} \\[0.5ex]
\midrule
Benzene & 29957 & 10.118 & 35333 & 9.654 & 37345 & 9.583 \\
Chlorobenzene & 65929 & 22.268 & 80397 & 21.968 & 85051 & 21.824 \\
1,2-dichlorobenzene & 87726 & 29.630 & 109342 & 29.876 & 116700 & 29.945 \\
Trichlorobenzene & 112455 & 37.983 & 140910 & 38.502 & 150623 & 38.649 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear to be the case that the `floatrow` package's code interacts in undesirable ways with that of the `rotating` package. Since it doesn't look like the `floatrow` package is truly needed, I wouldn't use it.

I would take care to structure the tables' headers so that they have a consistent look while avoiding line breaks in unfortunate places. Making sure that the three tables have (at least roughly) the same width also seems desirable.

[image]

```
\documentclass[A4, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,rotating,array}
\sisetup{group-digits=false}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
%\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\small
\centering

\caption{Sample A, B and C calculations}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l 
     S[table-format=5.0] C{1.55cm} 
     S[table-format=6.0] C{1.55cm}
     S[table-format=5.0] C{1.55cm} @{}} 
\hline\hline
\rule{0pt}{3.5ex}%
\textbf{Compound} & 
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.85cm}}{\textbf{Sample~A (area)}} & \textbf{\% A} & 
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.85cm}}{\textbf{Sample~B (area)}} & \textbf{\% B} & 
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.85cm}}{\textbf{Sample~C (area)}} & \textbf{\% C} \\ \addlinespace
\midrule
Benzene & 97166 & 29.796 & 118538 & 28.804 & 73071 & 34.719 \\
Chlorobenzene & 79837 & 24.482 & 101977 & 24.780 & 52619 & 25.002 \\
1,2-dichlorobenzene & 86195 & 26.432 & 111483 & 27.090 & 50634 & 24.058 \\
Trichlorobenzene & 62905 & 19.290 & 79534 & 19.326 & 34138 & 16.221 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%

\vspace{2.5\baselineskip}
\caption{Unknown 1, 2 and 3 calculations}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l 
            S[table-format=5.0] C{1.7cm}
       *{2}{S[table-format=6.0] C{1.7cm}} @{}}
\hline\hline
\rule{0pt}{3.5ex}%
\textbf{Compound} & 
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.7cm}}{\textbf{Unk~1 area}} & \textbf{Unk~1 area \% } & 
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.7cm}}{\textbf{Unk~2 area}} & \textbf{Unk~2 area \% } & 
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.7cm}}{\textbf{Unk~3 area}} & \textbf{Unk~3 area \% } \\ \addlinespace
\midrule
Benzene & 37439 & 13.666 & 44157 & 13.076 & 46672 & 12.987 \\
Chlorobenzene & 68335 & 24.943 & 83331 & 24.676 & 88155 & 24.531 \\
1,2-dichlorobenzene & 80497 & 29.382 & 100331 & 29.710 & 107083 & 29.798 \\
Trichlorobenzene & 87692 & 32.009 & 109881 & 32.538 & 117455 & 32.684 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%

\vspace{2.5\baselineskip}
\caption{Unknown 1, 2 and 3 calculations}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l 
               *{3}{S[table-format=6.0]S[table-format=2.3]} @{}}
\hline\hline
\rule{0pt}{3ex}%
\textbf{Compound} & 
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.6cm}}{\textbf{Unk~1 Corr.\ Area}} & \multicolumn{1}{C{1.8cm}}{\textbf{Unk~1 \%~Comp.}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.6cm}}{\textbf{Unk~2 Corr.\ Area}} & \multicolumn{1}{C{1.8cm}}{\textbf{Unk~2 \%~Comp.}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.6cm}}{\textbf{Unk~3 Corr.\ Area}} & \multicolumn{1}{C{1.8cm}}{\textbf{Unk~3 \%~Comp.}} \\ \addlinespace
\midrule
Benzene & 29957 & 10.118 & 35333 & 9.654 & 37345 & 9.583 \\
Chlorobenzene & 65929 & 22.268 & 80397 & 21.968 & 85051 & 21.824 \\
1,2-dichlorobenzene & 87726 & 29.630 & 109342 & 29.876 & 116700 & 29.945 \\
Trichlorobenzene & 112455 & 37.983 & 140910 & 38.502 & 150623 & 38.649 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to explain some of the coding choices:

- `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}`.

  `\newcolumntype` is a macro provided by the `array` package. Its use case is to create a new "column type" for use in `tabular`, `array`, and other table-like structures. Here, it is used to create a version of the basic `p` column type that centers the material rather than typesetting it fully justified.
- `\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{3}{S[table-format=6.0]S[table-format=2.3]} @{}}`

  Since the entries in the numeric columns are numeric, IMO it's a good idea to align them on their (present or implied) decimal marker. The `S` column type, provided by the `siunitx` package, performs such formatting. The option `table-format=6.0` informs LaTeX to set aside enough space for six digits before the (implied) decimal marker, and zero digits after the marker.

  The construct `*{3}{...}` informs LaTeX that there should be three instances of whatever is contained in `...`. To give another example, writing

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
  ```

  is easier to read and debug than `\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}` is, right?

  The `@{}` directives tell LaTeX *not* to provide any whitespace to the left of the first column or to the right of the final column.

Comment: thanks for modifying it; it looks great. Would you please explain what the `\begin{tabular}{@{} l 
               *{3}{S[table-format=6.0]S[table-format=2.3]} @{}}`
and `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}`
does?  I am not familiar with this. thanks again.