# booktabs rotating table

Tags: tables, rotating, booktabs, sidewaystable

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{center}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccc@{}}
\toprule
.... &.... & ........... & ...... & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}...../\\ 
.....\end{tabular} & .... & .... \\ \midrule

& Paper A & .... & & & & \\ \bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
\caption {...} 
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Can't seem to rotate my table. I copied the relevant code above. Error message is "Not in outer par mode. \begin" when I try to compile. If I remove the table environment it seems to work, but then the caption is at the bottom of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `sidewaystable` *is* a table environment. Also don't use the `center` environment: it adds unwanted spacing. Simply use this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccc@{}}
\toprule
.... &.... & ........... & ...... & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}...../\\ 
.....\end{tabular} & .... & .... \\ \midrule

& Paper A & .... & & & & \\ \bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\caption {...} 
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to also move the \caption so it appears like this:
\centering
\caption
....

Comment: In my test, the caption is centred (w.r.t. the table). Perhaps you have to compile twice.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. The caption still appeared underneath the table until I moved where it was located in the latex document.

Comment: It's not yet very clear to me: the caption must be rotated like the tabular, but above it (for the landscape layout, i.e. on the left for the  portrait layout)?

Comment: Yes, just as you describe. I wanted the caption above the table, like in this example:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253064/stack-three-tables-sideways